# How are web hosting companies able to give everyone public IPv4 addresses

Tags: networking, ip, hosting, ipv4

I've a few web applications on AWS/Linode/Digital Ocean/Hostgator's VPS instances and each has an IPv4 address. As I understand it, [APNIC](https://www.apnic.net/) and [ARIN](https://www.arin.net/) distribute IP addresses and new hosting companies have to buy unused IPs from ISPs going out of business.

1. Given how big AWS/GoDaddy/DigitalOcean etc. are now, and the ever growing number of websites and apps: How do these companies continue to fulfil the need for IP space? How're they able to give me public IPv4 Addresses for VPS instances?
2. How does an agency decide what sized pool of IPs can be given to which company. They're all profit-making companies at the end who are there for "land grab". The early movers seemingly have a big advantage in this — How does one make the field level-playing for new entrants?

Comment: These companies surely have big IPv4 spaces available. With bindings, they can use one IPv4 address to give access to thousands of websites.